# "Client Side Only Validation" in Partial Class-Checkmarx Vulnerability - Remediation

Tags: validation, client, checkmarx, secure-coding

Scanning codebase through the Checkmarx tool, I am getting "Client Side Only Validation" vulnerability, this point is raised wherever partial class is used.

Point 1:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Partial Class Frm_ChangePwd               //Checkmarx points to this line as vulnerability
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Point 2:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Partial Class Frm_changepassword        //Checkmarx points to this line as vulnerability
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
```

Checkmarx also gives this detail "No server side validation was found [path to code file]\Frm_changepassword.aspx.vb file, using only client side validation is not enough as it is easy to bypass"

Checkmarx raises this issues, whenever a partial class is used, but I'm not able to understand what exactly should I do to remediate this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This finding shows up because Checkmarx is not seeing any server side validators in your code. To be specific, it looks for the Page.IsValid property. I suggest to add a validation check using this property:

```
Page.Validate()

If Page.IsValid = True Then
....

Else
....
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. The developer only checked 'Page.IsValid' and Checkmarx closed the vulnerability.